# Equivalent of SSIS's Data Viewer, in Informatica PowerCenter Designer

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I'm looking for an equivalent of SSIS's Data Viewer, in Informatica PowerCenter Designer (IPCd). With Data Viewer you can see a snapshot of the data that is passed through by an ETL-component. I would like to have something similar with IPCd. The reason is that I want to see what happens, to see if components works as I want.

Though SSIS and IPCd are different in setup, and when running a package in SSIS the data flow is run and shown, and the flow of the mapping in IPCd is not shown when a workflow is running, I guess there is another way to see what every component does. Now I maken temporary tables between to see what happens and I guess there's a more efficient way to see what happens...

So, does anyone know a way to get an quivalent of SSIS's Data Viewer, in Informatica PowerCenter Designer, so I can see what every component does? Maybe changing something in the wf setup, or is there some option in the workflow monitor?

PS: for those not familiar with Data Viewer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137944.aspx

Comment: Unfortunatelly, there's no such thing in Mapping Designer. Only thing you can do is adding temporary objects (as you did) or run the Debugger (row-by-row, not really effective).
Now, with the new PowerCenter Developer tool you can run the mapping up to one certain transformation and take a peek. 
So it depends on the tool you use do design and run the mapping.

Comment: I use ipc 9.6.1. Which version is the new one you're talking about?

Comment: There are two tools in Informatica PowerCenter (including version 9.6.1): new Informatica Developer (that allows running a mapping to some point and viewing the data) and the older one PowerCenter Designer (which lacks this feature) To be precise this allowed in debug mode only.

Comment: thanks @Maciejg . I use Designer. I just found out I pointed to 'Developer' in this question. I'll change the question and explanation to 'Designer'. Anyway thanks for your answer: I'm no quite sure there isn't such anequivalent in Designer. Please add an answer to this question so I can rate it (elsewise I will do it some time).

Comment: thanks @Maciejg . I use Designer. I just found out I pointed to 'Developer' in this question. I'll change the question and explanation to 'Designer'. Anyway thanks for your answer: I'm now quite sure there isn't such anequivalent in Designer. Please add an answer to this question so I can rate it (elsewise I will do it some time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two tools in Informatica PowerCenter (including version 9.6.1):

- new Informatica Developer (that allows running a mapping to some point and viewing the data)
- and the older one PowerCenter Designer (which lacks this feature) To be precise this allowed in debug mode only

Unfortunatelly, there's no such thing in Mapping Designer. Only thing you can do is add temporary objects (as you did) or run the Debugger (row-by-row, not really effective). Now, with the new PowerCenter Developer tool you can run the mapping up to one certain transformation and take a peek. So it depends on the tool you use do design and run the mapping